# Exponential growth slower than linear growth?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-differential-equations

My question is about a step taken in the proof of Lemma 1.3 in *Stochastic Numerics for Mathematical Physics*

We have a system of SDEs denoted by:
\begin{equation}
dX(t) = a(t, X(t)) \text{d}t + \sum_{r=1}^q \sigma_r(t, x) \text{d}W_r(t)
\end{equation}

Now, the step in the proof that I do not follow is this:

> \begin{equation}\mathbb{E}\lvert X_{t,x}(t+\theta) - X_{t,y}(t+\theta) \rvert^2 \leq \lvert x - y \rvert^2 e^{Kh}, \end{equation}
> for $0 \leq \theta \leq h$ implies
>
> \begin{equation}\mathbb{E}\lvert X_{t,x}(t+h) - X_{t,y}(t+h) \rvert^2 \leq \lvert x - y \rvert^2 (1 + Kh). \end{equation}

Here, the subscript notation $X_{t, x}(s)$ denotes the initial condition, i.e. $X(t) = x$. Also, the positive constant $K$ can change value but is always independent of $h$.

How can bounding the expectation by something that grows exponentially imply that it is bounded by something growing linearly?

*Milstein, Grigori N.; Tretyakov, Michael V.*, Stochastic numerics for mathematical physics, Scientific Computation. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-21110-1/hbk; 978-3-642-05930-8/pbk). ixx, 594 p. (2004). [ZBL1085.60004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1085.60004).

EDIT: I have attached a picture of the complete proof below:

[image]

(1.2) is a globally Lipshcitz condition:
\begin{equation} \lvert a(t, x) - a(t, y) \rvert + \sum_{r=1}^q \lvert \sigma_r(t, x) - \sigma_r(t, y) \rvert \leq K \lvert x-y \rvert \end{equation}

Comment: Could you check that this is really the logical order of the inequalities? Usually you get a linear bound from the Lipschitz condition of the equation and then use the exponential bound as an easier way to deal with the resulting geometric sums.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, please see my edits, I added the order of steps and the globally Lipschitz condition.

Comment: Ok, your observations are correct. It seems like a genuine editing error or miscommunication. Either there was some earlier proof strategy that was then invalidated, but not in a fatal way, by the Grönwall proof. Or the statement in the inequality was always meant to be $|x-y|^2(1+Kh+O(h^2)$. Then you should find somewhere previously a note that only the leading error term will be written down.